# Handle missing values while multiply the lagged values of each group using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, lag

I have my data like as shown below

```
id  person_id Measurement   Value   UNIT
1     A1         Height      1.75      m
2     A1         Weight       64     kg
3     A2         Weight       71     kg
4     A2         Height      1.81     m 
5     A3         Height      1.89     m
6     A4         Weight      75      kg
7     A4         Height      1.76     m
```

I would like to calculate the BMI for each subject using the formula `BMI = (Weight) / (height * height)`

I was trying the below to get the values in one row so I can apply the formula but was encountering an error

```
SELECT *
    LAG(value) OVER(PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY id) val_prev1,
    LAG(value, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY id) val_prev2
  FROM 
(select * from table1)A
```

In the above code, am not sure how to factor in for missing records. **For ex, person_id = A3 doesn't have weight measurement and we need to put in NA and leave the BMI as NA as well**

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
Person_id  Measurement Value unit
   A1       BMI         20.8
   A2       BMI         XXX    #Multiplied value goes here
   A3       BMI         XXX  
   A4       BMI         XXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select person_id,
       (power(max(value) filter (where measurement = 'weight'), 2) /
        max(value) filter (where measurement = 'height')
       ) as bmi
from t
group by person_id;
```

You can also use the infix operator `^` to calculate the square.

In your example, the units are all consistent for the heights and weights.  If this is not the case in your actual data, ask a *new* question with an explanation of how to convert the values to the appropriate units.

Comment: Thanks. upvoted. So, instead of `power`, we can use `^` operator?

Comment: @TheGreat . . . Yes; I think the two are exactly equivalent in Postgres  -- but they do the same thing.

Comment: May I also know which part of the code results in putting `NULL` or leaving `empty` when one or both of the measurements is missing (either height or weight)

Comment: @TheGreat . . . The `filter` will filter out all rows, if there is no "height" or "weight" for a given person.  The `max()` would then return `NULL`.